# Get lastest version of mono

Tags: mono

What is the best way to get the latest version of mono on ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure it's the best option, but i use the repository of [badgerports](http://badgerports.org/)
About badgerports:

> badgerports is a software repository
>   for use with Ubuntu Linux 10.04.
>   Whilst on the whole it is a good idea
>   to use the software provided with your
>   Linux distribution, there are
>   sometimes bugs or major software
>   updates that cannot be included for
>   operational reasons. badgerports is a
>   home for a number of wayward software
>   packages, to enhance the Ubuntu
>   experience.
>
> The primary purpose of badgerports is
>   to provide recent versions of the Mono
>   framework, and associated packages
>   such as F-Spot, Banshee, and
>   Monodevelop. Suggestions for other
>   packages to include are welcome, but
>   don't be offended if I decline for
>   whatever reason.whatever reason.

You can find the instructions on how to use it [here](http://badgerports.org/help.html)